# Angular ngx/core translator doesn't translate a few translations

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I've had a problem with Angular's core translator. There are just a few translations which just don't get translated. Often, these few translations are added just today or the past days.

In the de.json and en.json are translations for these words that should get translated.

Did anyone experience such a problem too? How can I solve it?